# How i place an image to the bottom of the display?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to desing a rotary half wheel menu on android with eclipse. I have a full wheel image and I want to place it to the bottom of screen. I must place that full wheel's midpoint on the bottom of screen for obtaining half wheel menu. I have tried that code on xml

[image]

Its simulation on emulator did not satisfy me. Because the wheel image is on the center of screen. I want it to place on the bottom for my rotary half wheel menu application. I also know that I can set it with `android:layout_marginTop="600dp"` , but I want to provide compatibility of other screen sizes on mobile phones which use android operating system.

Comment: Try to wrap your `RootView` with `RelativeLayout` and use `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` property inside `View`which u need at the bottom of screen .

Comment: why don't you halve the rotary picture and align it at the bottom of the page?

Comment: it is about my job @NicholasTJ . This was wanted from me, i can not cut the image.

Comment: ok, I'm just curious, because I can't get my picture to show only half at the bottom of the screen. :)

Comment: Don't worry, me too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `RelativeLayout` Outside of that image and set property in image `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`

like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: it seems it will work with some corrections. Thank you @chirag saga .

Comment: I will ask you one more question about that @chirag saga :) I want to place the center of full wheel at the bottom of the screen. I don't want to see a full wheel at the bottom. I want to see half wheel. I hope i'm clear :)

Comment: For that you can set `layout_marginBottom` to -yourImageWidth for example `android:layout_marginBottom="-200dp"` I hope I understand you right...